# How do I define custom exceptions across multiple files?

Tags: python, exception

So I have a Python project that is split across multiple files (to preserve my sanity) and I'm trying to use a custom exception defined in one file in a different file. Basically, I have `a.py` and `b.py`. `a.py` contains a custom exception (`customException`) that is raised by a function within `a.py`.

`a.py`:

```
class customException(Exception):
   [irrelevant error handling]

def aFunction():
   if [something]:
      raise customException

   return [stuff]
```

The surrounding code is irrelevant (I hope, otherwise I have a much weirder issue) so I didn't include it. I then import `a.py` into `b.py` (they're in the same directory) to use aFunction:

`b.py`:

```
import a.py

try:
   var = a.aFunction()
except customException:
   var = [something else]
```

When I run `b.py` in a situation where `a.py` would raise customException, I get the expected `a.customException` error, but I also get a `NameError: name 'customException' is not defined` error.

How do I make it so that `customException` is defined in `b.py`?

**Edit:** Paul M.'s solution worked for me just in case anyone else finds this when looking for a solution. Thanks again Paul and everyone else who answered!

Comment: Just like you prefaced `aFunction` with `a.`, you would say `except a.customException:`.

Comment: Don't `import a.py`.  Just `import a`.  Then use `a.customException`, or you can do `from a import customException` and then just use `customException`.  By leave the `.py` out of your imports.

Comment: another way would be to use `from a import *`, just  import everything and then refer the function directly instead of `a.aFunction()`

Comment: Thank you @PaulM, your solution worked! I don't know if its kosher on StackOverflow to thank people in comments (like how you shouldn't edit posts on Reddit without saying so), but I want to show my appreciation for your quick and accurate answer :)

Comment: @Alix No worries. You haven't done anything wrong ;)

Comment: Suggest you read and start following the [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) in the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to qualify `customException` by calling it as `a.customException` from modules where you imported `a`, like so:

`a.py`:

```
class customException(Exception):
   [irrelevant error handling]

def aFunction():
   if [something]:
      raise customException

   return [stuff]
```

`b.py`:

```
import a

try:
   var = a.aFunction()
except a.customException:
   var = [something else]
```

Comment: Thanks! Paul M. also suggested this in the comments to my question and it worked! I probably should have realized my mistake before asking my question, but since I didn't I'm very grateful to helpful people like you :)